# How to read file and apply substitutions to its content?

Tags: nix

I have a long string which I want to extract to a separate file.

```
prepare = lib.hm.dag.entryAfter ["writeBoundary"] '' very long script with ${...} '';
```

I can read it with `builtins.readFile` but it does not replace `${...}` nix place holders.

How can I read string from a file and resolve nix variables inside it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `substitute` family of bash functions (see [Nixpkgs manual](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/)) or use the `substituteAll` Nix function which produces a derivation that performs the substitution.

```hs
substituteAll { src = ./sample.sh; inherit bash; hi = hello; }
```

`sample.sh`:

```
#!@bash@/bin/bash
@hi@
```

Result:

```
$ nix repl <nixpkgs>

nix-repl> substituteAll { src = ./sample.sh; inherit bash; hi = hello; }
«derivation /nix/store/7klv763a0ipgvwf3j84aazkzx2d5rljz-sample.sh.drv»

nix-repl> :b substituteAll { src = ./sample.sh; inherit bash; hi = hello; }

this derivation produced the following outputs:
  out -> /nix/store/v03hpzw9ykrbyqpmalnijnyibq3waqhw-sample.sh

nix-repl>
```

`/nix/store/v03hpzw9ykrbyqpmalnijnyibq3waqhw-sample.sh`:

```
#!/nix/store/a4yw1svqqk4d8lhwinn9xp847zz9gfma-bash-4.4-p23/bin/bash
/nix/store/jmmw0d3nmklwafcwylvrjb9v69wrbcxf-hello-2.10
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass entire sets to this function? I.e `@pkgs.coreutils.out@`

Comment: You could write a function to achieve something similar, but the derivation will depend on all of the attributes, which may not be desirable, certainly with `pkgs`. (`substituteAll ({ src = ./sample.sh; } // yourOwnFlatteningFunction x)`).
Maybe a good alternative is to put the `''`-quoted Nix string in its own file, make it a function of `pkgs` and use `import ./sample.sh pkgs`.